# Python text extraction from letter - index

Tags: python, nlp, text-extraction

I want to extract a certain part of a letter from a txt file with Python. The beginning and the ending is marked by clear beginning / ending expressions (letter_begin / letter_end). My problem is that the "recording" of the text needs to start at the very first occurence of any item in the letter_begin list and end at the very last item in the letter_end list (+3 lines buffer). I want to write the output text to file. Here is my sample text and my code so far:

```
sample_text = """Some random text right here 
.........
Dear Shareholders: We are pleased to provide this report to our shareholders and fellow shareholders. we thank you for your continued support.
Best regards, 
Douglas - Director


Other random text in this lines """

letter_begin = ["dear", "to our shareholders", "fellow shareholders"]
letter_end = ["best regards", "respectfully submitted", "thank you for your continued support"]

with open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as infile, open(xyz.txt, mode = 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f: 
        text = infile.read()
        lines = text.strip().split("\n")
        target_start_idx = None
        target_end_idx = None
        for index, line in enumerate(lines):
            line = line.lower()
            if any(beg in line for beg in letter_begin):
                target_start_idx = index
                continue
            if any(end in line for end in letter_end):
                target_end_idx = index + 3
                break


        if target_start_idx is not None:
            target = "\n".join(lines[target_start_idx : target_end_idx])
            f.write(str(target))
```

my desired output should be:

```
output = "Dear Shareholders: We are pleased to provide this report to our shareholders and fellow shareholders. we thank you for your continued support.
    Best regards, 
    Douglas - Director

    "
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop gives you the **last** occurrence of an opening sequence.

You should separate the read part into two loops, like this:

```
with open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as infile:

    text = infile.read()
    lines = text.strip().split("\n")
    target_start_idx = None
    target_end_idx = None
    for index, line in enumerate(lines):
        line = line.lower()
        if any(beg in line for beg in letter_begin):
            target_start_idx = index
            break
    for index, line in enumerate(lines):
        if any(end in line for end in letter_end):
            target_end_idx = index + 3
            continue
```

In this way, you exit the loop when the **first** occurrence of an opening sequence appears.

Comment: thanks a lot! your solution captures the first occurence in both cases, correct? But I want to have the last occurence in the second case (letter_end) - any idea how to do this?

Comment: Yes, the idea is that the loop should continue running until all lines are compared against letter_end. I've edited the code to reflect this.